# jQuery unable to stop form submission on return key even with event.stopPropogation, event.preventDefault and return false

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, form-submit, preventdefault, stoppropagation

I have just built a custom autocomplete component using jquery. My problem is that when somebody uses the keyboard up/down arrow key to select one of the autocomplete suggestion and hits return, form submission happens even though I call `event.stopPropogation()` and `event.preventDefault()` and also return false.

I have bound the core function to the keyup event:

```
$('#'+id).keyup(function(event){ getResults(event,this,url,method,data,setEl,makeLink,cssClass); event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation(); return false;});
```

getResults makes an ajax call to a server script that returns json object.
getResults pseudocode is as follows:

```
function getResults(event,element,url,method,data,setEl,makeLink,cssClass) {
    $(element).css("position","inherit");
var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
if (keyCode == 40){ //down arrow key
    if ($("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").is("li")) { // some li is already on hover!
        if ($("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").is($("#ac_"+element.id+" li").last())) {
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").removeClass("hover");
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" li").first().addClass("hover");
        } else {
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").removeClass("hover").next().addClass("hover");
        }
    } else {
        $("#ac_"+element.id+" li").first().addClass("hover");
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} else if (keyCode == 38){ //up arrow key
    if ($("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").is("li")) { // some li is already on hover!
        if ($("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").is($("#ac_"+element.id+" li").first())) {
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").removeClass("hover");
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" li").last().addClass("hover");
        } else {
            $("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").removeClass("hover").prev().addClass("hover");
        }
    } else {
        $("#ac_"+element.id+" li").last().addClass("hover");
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
} else if (keyCode == 13){ //return key
    if ($("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").is("li")) { // some li is already on hover!
        $("#ac_"+element.id+" .hover").removeClass("hover").trigger("click");
        
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

if (setEl) { if (!$(element).val() || $(element).val()=="") { $("#"+setEl).val('');} }
if ($(element).val() != autocomplete_prev_search[element.id]) {
    $("#ac_"+element.id).remove();
}
autocomplete_prev_search[element.id] = $(element).val();
if ($(element).val().length>=3) {
    if (!url){return;}
    if (!data) {
        data = {match:$(element).val()};
    } else {
        data.match = $(element).val();
    }
    if (!method) { method = "POST"; }
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(result){ return resultHandler(result,element.id,setEl,makeLink,event); },
        beforeSend: function(){ $(element).css("background-image","url('/kit/icons/indeterminate.gif')").css("background-repeat","no-repeat").css("background-position","right center"); },
        complete:function(){ $(element).css("background-image","none"); },
        error: errorHandler,
        timeout: 1000,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
    return false;
}
```

Finally the success handler of the ajax call is as follows:

```
function resultHandler(result, id, setEl, makeLink, event) {
    $("#ac_"+id).remove();
if (result && result.length>0) {
    var $ul = $("<ul id='ac_"+id+"' class='autocomplete'></ul>");
    var $li;
    for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i]) {
            if (makeLink) {
                $li = $("<li onclick=\"location.href='/"+result[i].type+"/"+result[i].id+"'\">"+result[i].type+" '"+result[i].title+"'</li>");
            } else {
                if (!setEl) {
                    $li = $("<li onclick=\"$('#"+id+"').val('"+result[i].id+"'); return killEvent(event);\">"+result[i].type+" '"+result[i].title+"'</li>");
                } else {
                    $li = $("<li onclick=\"$('#"+setEl+"').val('"+result[i].id+"'); $('#"+id+"').val('"+result[i].title+"');return killEvent(event);\">"+result[i].type+" '"+result[i].title+"'</li>");
                }
            }
            //$li.click(function(){ location.href="/"+result[i].type+"/"+result[i].id; });
            // doesn't work as the click function has no access to result[i] object
            $ul.append($li);
        }
    }
    var left = $('#'+id).offset().left;
    var top = $('#'+id).offset().top+$('#'+id).outerHeight();
    $ul.css("width",$("#"+id).css("width")).css("left",left+"px").css("top",top+"px");
    $ul.insertAfter('#'+id);
}
    return false;
}
```

And lastly, killEvent is a simple function :

```
function killEvent(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
if (keyCode == 13) {
    event.stopPropogation();
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
    }
}
```

So, all the handlers and even the click on the `li` element of the autocomplete suggestion list are all returning false and calling `stopPropogation` and `preventDefault`. However, the form submission still occurs! What am i doing wrong or missing here. Sorry for the long post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found a way in which to stop the default event of the browser when return key is pressed while doing a selection of the autocomplete suggestion using keyboard's up/down key and enter!

```
$('#'+id).keydown(function(event){ return handleKey(event); });
$('#'+id).keyup(function(event){ return getResults(event,this,url,method,data,setEl,makeLink,cssClass); });
```

Where on keydown, the handleKey function simply checks for keycode 13 and then calls stopPropagation and preventDefault!

Here's the handleKey function

```
function handleKey(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
    if (keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thus I cancel the default action of the browser on keydown!
On keyup, the getResults simply checks and returns if there is a selection!

The trick is that to stop the default action of the browser, we have to act on keydown and not on keyup!

Thanks all especially CronosS for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the key up event, handle the submit event. Add a check in there to make sure that everything is complete, if not then do the return false.

Comment: Nope, the entire autocomplete setup is bound to the keyup event on the textbox it has to act on! Another issue is that I want to make this autocomplete generic. So all I am trying to achieve is that it traps the return key on the textbox it's bound to and simply uses the value selected however, doesn't let the form submit!

Comment: @DeeTee That's the point. You prevent the default action of the browser on key up, while the browser send the form before: on key down.

Comment: @DeeTee if you don't want the form to submit, the simplest thing you can do is handle the submit event so that it only submits when all criteria have been met. Otherwise don't use a form in your html for submission but rather do an Ajax post trough the submit button click.

Comment: @CronosS I didn't know that the browser acts on keydown. I'll try changing the binding to trigger the autocomplete to keydown and see! Thanks meanwhile :)